# Accessing parameter from Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am using highcharts 4 javascript library.
In highcharts, you can customize the buttons for the chart.

[Chart with custom button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3bla.png)

The way to do that is to push the buttons (as an object) in an array and then include this array in the Highcharts configuration.

The problem is that when I click on the button, I am having trouble accessing the parameters attached to each function

The code below shows how I create the array of buttons:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr_papers.length; i++)
{
                var caption = arr_papers[i].caption;
                var colid = arr_papers[i].colid;
                
                buttons.push({
                    text: caption,
                    id : colid,
                    onclick: function () {
                        loadPerformanceBarChart(colid, caption);
                    }
                });
}
```

Then in the Highcharts configutation, I included the above array:

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                renderTo: 'bar_chart_stats'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Num Students per Range'
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        menuItems: buttons
                    }
                }
            },
.
.
.
.
```

The problem is that when the `loadPerformanceBarChart` function is called, the parameters `colid, caption` are the last ones from the array.

How can I find a way around? Thank you..

Comment: Use `let` or `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: Found the solution:

for (var i = 0; i < arr_papers.length; i++) {
  (function () {
    var caption = arr_papers[i].caption;
    var colid = arr_papers[i].colid;

    buttons.push({
      text: caption,
      id: colid,
      onclick: function () {
        loadPerformanceBarChart(colid, caption);
      },
    });
  })();
}

Comment: The onclick function will use the final values of colid and caption for all buttons, which might not be what you expect. To fix this, you can use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to create a new scope for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: That is an extremely outdated method. Just use `let` or `const` to declare the variables.

Comment: Yes you are right. Using `let` made it work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variables using `let` or `const` for block scoping.

```js
const caption = arr_papers[i].caption, colid = arr_papers[i].colid;
```